# Biblatex not working with VSCode

Tags: biblatex, biber, vscode, latex-workshop

I have been using Overleaf for several years, but I am trying to switch to compiling LaTeX documents locally as I am starting much larger projects now and I would like to be able to insert figures automatically. I have the following setup which works perfectly fine on Overleaf, but I am unable to get it to work on VSCode. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am using the LaTeX Workshop extension in VSCode and I am trying to use biblatex without success. My operating system is Windows 11.

Here is my minimum example TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{np-breakeven.bib}

\begin{document}
Hello \cite{banzhaf_bundling_2022}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where `np-breakeven.bib` is the bib file with the following content:

```
@article{banzhaf_bundling_2022,
    title = {Bundling Private Complements to Finance Public Goods},
    volume = {98},
    issn = {0023-7639, 1543-8325},
    url = {http://le.uwpress.org/lookup/doi/10.3368/le.98.3.082621-0099},
    doi = {10.3368/le.98.3.082621-0099},
    pages = {440--460},
    number = {3},
    journaltitle = {Land Economics},
    shortjournal = {Land Economics},
    author = {Banzhaf, H. Spencer and Smith, V. Kerry},
    urldate = {2023-07-17},
    date = {2022-08},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Banzhaf and Smith - 2022 - Bundling Private Complements to Finance Public Goo.pdf:C\:\\Users\\wmrobin3\\Zotero\\storage\\LDTY6SY6\\Banzhaf and Smith - 2022 - Bundling Private Complements to Finance Public Goo.pdf:application/pdf},
}
```

My settings for LaTeX Workshop are

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "--shell-escape", // if you want to have the shell-escape flag
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%.tex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "bibtex",
            "command": "bibtex",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "biber",
            "command": "biber",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "command": "xelatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        }
    ],

    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "tools": [
              "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "xelatex -> biber -> xelatex*2",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex",
                "biber",
                "xelatex",
                "xelatex"
            ]
        }
      ],

      "latex-workshop.intellisense.citation.backend": "biblatex"
```

and I am trying to compile the PDF through the recipe `xelatex -> biber -> xelatex*2` but I am getting a weird error that says `! LaTeX Error: File 'biblatex.sty' not found.` but there should be no need for a `biblatex.sty` file when I am using LaTeX Workshop, right?

Comment: You are loading `biblatex.sty` in your document with the line `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`. Somehow the package can't be found on your system. This has, most likely, nothing to do with VS Code, you could try compiling your document on the command line to check if the error occurs there too

Comment: Welcome. Run `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` from your terminal/commandline. Does it find the file? If not, there might be a problem with your `$PATH`. Maybe your TeX distro wasn't set up correctly. What OS are you running and which TeX distro do you use? BTW there is no need to run `xelatex` if you don't load system fonts etc. (of course, it neither should throw an error)

Comment: @DG' I get the same error when compiling the document from the command line. This suggests that it is not an error with VS Code or the extension, correct?

Comment: @lukeflo When I run this in the terminal I get no result. This suggests that the file `biblatex.sty` is missing, right? I am using Windows 11 (I updated the question to reflect this) but I don't know how to identify the TeX distro. How do I do this?

Comment: How did you install Latex? Try run it from your Powershell instead of simple commandline. And yes, its not a VS Code error.

Comment: @lukeflo I never explicitly installed anything. I only used VS Code with the Latex Workshop extension.

Comment: OK. Then it can not work. You need to install a Latex distro. Latex Workshop is just an extension for VS Code which offers code highlighting, auto completion etc. but not the software (La)TeX itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments its clear you're missing a LaTeX distro. Thus, it cannot work since VS Code doesn't install the TeX engine itself.

Look out for [TeXLive](https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html) or [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/download). I would go with the former, but that's purely personal preference.

After you've installed TeX, you're code should work.

Comment: This solved the issue I was having. Thank you.

Comment: Happy that I could help. Have fun TeXing!